# counting occurences of the smallest number in an array

Tags: c++

i am trying to find the number of occurences of the smalles number in an array, but something seems to be wrong. I don't get the right results. Can you help me ?

```
#include<iostream>

void readArray(int elements, int* array)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < elements; index++)
        std::cin >> array[index];
}

int main()
{
    int *array, elements;
    std::cout << "Number of elements: ";
    std::cin >> elements;

    array = new int[elements];
    readArray(elements, array);

    int min = array[0];
    int count = 1;

    for (int index = 1; index < elements; ++index)
    {
        if (array[index] = min)
            count++;
        else
            if (array[index] < min)
            {
                count = 1;
                min = array[index];
            }
    }

    std::cout << "Minimum is:  " << min;
    std::cout << "\nNumber of occurences is: " << count << "\n";

    //cleanup
    delete(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (array[index] = min)` is an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: @GoverNator but here it is almost right to start in 1. The code uses element 0 to initialize the minimum, then it goes from 1 to end to check the rest of elements for minimums. I just say "almost" because some checking of the number of elements in the input would be nice, just in case it was 0 input elements.

Comment: I can add the small details afterwards, they are not really necessary, what i needed is the algorythm.

Comment: it doesn't need to be the smallest, it's working

Comment: `delete[] array`!

Comment: @DanielLangr OP resets counter when smaller number is found so it doesn't matter

Comment: @DanielLangr to initialize the min value before starting the loop, I think it is a good approach. Or maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @JorgeY. thanks, I should be more attentieve

Comment: @GoverNator It happens to everybody, little details are easy to miss :)

Comment: done it .......

Answer (score 0):

This comparison is wrong:

```
if (array[index] = min)
```

You need to use double equal as comparison operator:

```
if (array[index] == min)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't notice. I learned Pascal in highschool and sometimes it still hunts me.

Comment: @AlinChirita Please look also at the comment to your question by Killzone Kid about using `delete [] array` instead of `delete array` when you have reserved memory by using new []. Choosing the wrong way to delete things is a typical rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the smallest number, then just use [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).
 To get the smallest number before counting, just use [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). Basically, your problem reduces to a few lines of code if you just use the facilities already provided in the standard library.

Comment: This would be inefficient. You need 2 passes over the array, while OP's code just 1.

Comment: @Daniel Langr in most cases that doesn't matter. *Most* code is not in a hot path, and even when it is, containers are usually small. IMHO; readable code beats efficient code when the efficiency doesn't *actually* matter.

Comment: I agree, we don't know the motivation/details here. The array is read from standard input, so it will likely be very small, but it can be only for purpose of MCVE.

Comment: This problem is a litle part from a university homework, so i am not allowed to use STL.

Comment: Also, i have to do it using only one iteration, and i don't know wich is the smallest number

Comment: @AlinChirita You should clarify these requirements in the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I pointed that out mostly because your answer can be read by someone for whom the efficiency does matter. Otherwise, I would use the same solution, that's why I upvoted.

Comment: @Alin Chirita "not allowed to use the STL", why? That's just stupid and counterproductive if you ever want to write code for real life projects. Sure, there can be a learning experience in doing everything from scratch, but in the real world noone (or *very few* people) ever does that - it's a waste of time/effort.

Comment: @Daniel Langr +1

Comment: we are just learning to code in c++! we are not allowed to do it FOR THE MOMENT, until we learn the algorythms

Comment: @Alin Chirita - you are asking how to do something, I assume you want the answer most professionals would go with. I don't assume you are a student needing to learn basic algorithm stuff. SO is supposed to be a Q/A site for professionals; not a "teach the green-horns" forum.